# Get Data from Axios and Store in interface Contains Multiple array in Type Script

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Hi Guys I have a Problem when i want to get Request from Axios through api than when i set selected data from axios in userDetail interface it gives error.
please check sand box i have put all code and data format that returns from api

[This is Code Sandbox all data of api and axios request is in it](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-neco-1te3ms?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

Here are my changes
[Modified sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/young-tdd-gw89sm?file=/src/App.tsx)

1. userDetail(id: string) returns you a list of user info, no single user info. Advice: Name your methods with what they do. userDetail has no verb. So it could be getUserDetail, updateUserDetail, deleteUserDetail and so on.

```js
//old code
userDetail: (id: string) =>
  axios.get<userDetail[]>(`/User/GetUserByID/${id}`),

//Correct
userDetail: (id: string) =>
    axios.get<userDetail>(`/User/GetUserByID/${id}`)
```

2. Your state type was wrong.
   Advice: Name types, interfaces PascalCase [Some typescript guidelines](https://google.github.io/styleguide/tsguide.html)

```js
/// your version array of any OR userDetail. I believe you want to store a single user detail
const [userDetails,setUserDetail]=useState<userDetail | []>([])


///correct
const [userDetails, setUserDetail] = useState<userDetail | undefined>()
```

3. You had issues with loading. You were not waiting the proimse.

```js
/// your version
  useEffect(()=>{
    // Agent File to access axios Request
    const result= agent.createUser.userDetail("1")
    setUserDetail(result);
  },[])

/// correct using Promise.then. Note that error is not handled

  useEffect(() => {
    // Agent File to access axios Request
    agent.createUser.userDetail("1").then((axiosResponse) => {
      setUserDetail(axiosResponse.data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);

// correct using async await

useEffect(() => {
  //declare it
  const loadUserDetail = async () {
    const axiosResponse = await agent.createUser.userDetail("1");
    setUserDetail(axiosResponse.data);
    setIsLoading(false);
  }

  //call it
  loadUserDetail();
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks alot You Save My Time  The Result is Fixed I will apply it on My Works